# how can we use combos in jface tableviewer columns

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I am reading excel data and taking headers(only first row) as my columns and added to list and this list is added as input to my tableviewer to display data in my table.I am creating tablecolumns and added the label provider. I am able to see the data in the table. Now i want to display the all textboxes as combos in each column . How can i can add combos for each column? my code is like
my tableviewer class

```java
public class TableViewerExample {

   public TableViewerExample(Shell shell) {
       TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);


       TableViewerColumn upDownColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       upDownColumn.getColumn().setText("Display Order");
       upDownColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       upDownColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getDisplayOrder();
           }
       });

       TableViewerColumn checkboxColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       checkboxColumn.getColumn().setText("Checkbox Selection");
       checkboxColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       checkboxColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getCheckboxSelection();
           }
       });

       TableViewerColumn uniqueFieldsColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       uniqueFieldsColumn.getColumn().setText("Unique Fields");
       uniqueFieldsColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       uniqueFieldsColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getUniqueFields();
           }
       });

       TableViewerColumn inputFieldNameColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       inputFieldNameColumn.getColumn().setText("Input Field Name");
       inputFieldNameColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       inputFieldNameColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getInputFieldName();
           }
       });

       TableViewerColumn dataTypeColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       dataTypeColumn.getColumn().setText("Data Type");
       dataTypeColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       dataTypeColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getDataType();
           }
       });


       TableViewerColumn inputFieldFormatColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       inputFieldFormatColumn.getColumn().setText("Input Field Format");
       inputFieldFormatColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       inputFieldFormatColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getInputFieldFormat();
           }
       });


       TableViewerColumn displayNameColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       displayNameColumn.getColumn().setText("Display Name");
       displayNameColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       displayNameColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getDisplayName();
           }
       });


       TableViewerColumn displayFormatColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
       displayFormatColumn.getColumn().setText("Display Format");
       displayFormatColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);

       displayFormatColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

           @Override
           public String getText(Object element) {
               return ((DataSourceModel) element).getDisplayFormat();
           }
       });


       viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
       System.out.println(RetrieveExcelData.getDataSourceFieldsList());
       viewer.setInput(RetrieveExcelData.getDataSourceFieldsList());
       viewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
       viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Display display = new Display();

       Shell shell = new Shell(display);
       shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
       new TableViewerExample(shell);
       shell.open();

       while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
           if (!display.readAndDispatch())
               display.sleep();
       }
       display.dispose();
   }
```

setinput class

```java
 public class RetrieveExcelData {

     public static List getDataSourceFieldsList() {

          String filename = "D:\\ServiceOrders_point_Org_morethan500.xlsx";

             List<List<XSSFCell>> sheetData = new ArrayList<>();

             try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {

                 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                         XSSFSheet myExcelSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                         XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow )myExcelSheet.getRow(0);
                         Iterator cells=row.cellIterator();
                         List<XSSFCell> data = new ArrayList<>();

                         while (cells.hasNext()) { 
                             XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next(); 
                             data.add(cell); 
                             } 
                         sheetData.add(data);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
             return showExcelData(sheetData);

     }

      private static List  showExcelData(List<List<XSSFCell>> sheetData) {
              List<DataSourceModel> resultList = new ArrayList();
             // Iterates the data and print it out to the console.
             for (List<XSSFCell> data : sheetData) {
                 for (XSSFCell cell : data) {
                     DataSourceModel dataSourceModel=new DataSourceModel(cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue(), cell.getStringCellValue());
                     resultList.add(dataSourceModel);
                 }
             }
             return resultList;
         }
```

my model class

```java
public class DataSourceModel {

    private String displayOrder;
    private String checkboxSelection;
    private String uniqueFields;
    private String inputFieldName;
    private String dataType;
    private String inputFieldFormat;
    private String displayName;
    private String displayFormat;

    public DataSourceModel(String displayOrder,String checkboxSelection,String uniqueFields,String inputFieldName,String dataType, String inputFieldFormat, String displayName,String displayFormat) {
        this.displayOrder=displayOrder;
        this.checkboxSelection=checkboxSelection;
        this.uniqueFields=uniqueFields;
        this.inputFieldName=inputFieldName;
        this.dataType=dataType;
        this.inputFieldFormat=inputFieldFormat;
        this.displayName=displayName;
        this.displayFormat=displayFormat;
    }

    public String getDisplayOrder() {
        return displayOrder;
    }
    public void setDisplayOrder(String displayOrder) {
        this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    }
    public String getCheckboxSelection() {
        return checkboxSelection;
    }
    public void setCheckboxSelection(String checkboxSelection) {
        this.checkboxSelection = checkboxSelection;
    }
    public String getUniqueFields() {
        return uniqueFields;
    }
    public void setUniqueFields(String uniqueFields) {
        this.uniqueFields = uniqueFields;
    }
    public String getInputFieldName() {
        return inputFieldName;
    }
    public void setInputFieldName(String inputFieldName) {
        this.inputFieldName = inputFieldName;
    }
    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }
    public String getInputFieldFormat() {
        return inputFieldFormat;
    }
    public void setInputFieldFormat(String inputFieldFormat) {
        this.inputFieldFormat = inputFieldFormat;
    }
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
    public String getDisplayFormat() {
        return displayFormat;
    }
    public void setDisplayFormat(String displayFormat) {
        this.displayFormat = displayFormat;
    }
```

and the table looks like

[image]

Now i want to make combos instead of text in the columns . Colud you please help how can i change to combos instead of text boxes using my code for all

Comment: You can use a `ComboBoxCellEditor` cell editor with `TableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport` to change a cell to a combo when the user clicks on it. Showing a combo for every cell all the time is more complex and you may get 'out of handle' problems if you have many rows.

Comment: ok. I wrote sample code above  .I didnt fail to make combos using sample model..In my application , combo is displayed based on user clicks only. almost 500 headers are there in my excel . I am taking those as list to tableviewer input. In my model there are 3-4 combos using renderers .But somehow ,i am able to open only one table with all the data(huge data). If i am trying to load another table in editor (keeping the lfirst table as it is in one editor) with same data, i am getting swt handlers error .May i know root cause for this handlers error?

Comment: If you are on Windows there is a restriction on the number of controls you can have - you get a 'no more handles' error if you go over this. This is a Windows restriction rather than SWT. You must rework your code to use less controls.

Comment: Colud you please let me know limit of controls(any nunmber) that can we use to avoid handlers error

Comment: I don't use Windows anymore so I don't know what the current limit is.